# How does Google's Universal Sentence Encoder deal with out-of-vocabulary terms?

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

It seems to output embeddings even for random jibberish, and the similarity is even high for this particular pair of jibberish.

```
np.inner(embed('sdasdasSda'), embed('sadasvdsaf'))
```

```
array([[0.70911765]], dtype=float32)
```

I'm wondering how sentences are tokenized and what preprocessing steps are done internally. Also, how is the embedding model trained? As I understand it, they use a Deep Averaging Network, which is another neural network applied on the average of the individual word embeddings?

Comment: This can be related [link](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/g/hub/c/6ZH6UzKtwgA). It seems that there are some OOV buckets (not sure how they were computed) and with a use of hash function we can map a OOV word to that bucket (or buckets)